# Heroku Nginx-PHP custom php.ini

Tags: php, heroku, nginx

Can I use my own file *custom_php.ini*, if I use Nginx?

Here is my *Procfile*:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 -i custom_php.ini
vendor/bin/heroku-php-nginx -C nginx_app.conf
```

*custom_php.ini*:

```
extension = /app/ext/siphash.so
```

*nginx_app.conf*:

```
location /news/space/ {
        proxy_pass http://nasa.gov/;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can.

Looks like your `Procfile` is malformed (assuming you copy/pasted correctly). It should read:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-nginx -i custom_php.ini -C nginx_app.conf
```

It might be a good idea to copy the default `php.ini` (https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/blob/master/conf/php/php.ini) to `custom_php.ini` and add your customizations.

You can also quickly and easily re-define the document root like this (to folder public/ inside the app):

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-nginx -i custom_php.ini -C nginx_app.conf public/
```

By the way, if you have PHP 5.5.11+ and Nginx installed locally, try `composer require --dev "heroku/heroku-buildpack-php *"` and then `foreman start`. That should boot a server on localhost, port 5000, using your `Procfile` and with all the same settings as on Heroku.